# SQL pivot using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I am looking for a solution to use pivot on two tables. My problem though, number/name of column & row headers exist as rows in third table. My third table looks like this:

```
ID      Name
1       Row1
1       Row2
1       Row3
2       Col1
2       Col2
2       Col3
```

My final solution should look like this:

```
         Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4 .........    Total
Row1      4       2     4      2                 12

Row2      2    ...................              ...

Row3      7  ....................                ...

....

Total     12      14    6      3                 80
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use the new [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator.

Comment: It cannot take the column names from a table, they should be hardcoded